# How to combine similar levels of factor variable through a common keyword

Tags: r

I have a factor variable of a very large data set about personal loans, with 6000 levels. Many of these levels are similar e.g. "Credit Card Loan" and "Credit Card Repayment", or "Car Purchase" and "Car Loan". Is there a way I can relevel this factor variable conditional on the level containing a key word, e.g. "Credit" or "Car"?

I have releveled factor variables manually when there are far fewer levels but due to the large size of the dataset I need an automatic way to group the levels.

example:

```r
x <- factor(c("Credit Card", "Car Loan", "Credit Card Repayment", 
              "Mortgage", "Car Financing"))
```

desired output:

```r
x
#[1] Credit  Car  Mortgage
```

Comment: I guess you have to use some NLP here with levenstien distance or some other parameter

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say for sure without more detail, but something like

```
x <- ifelse(grep("Car",x,fixed=TRUE), "Car",
            ifelse(grep("Credit", x, fixed=TRUE), "Credit",
                   ifelse(grep("Mortgage", x, fixed=TRUE), "Mortgage",
                          NA)))
```

should work. (That will produce a string, you can make it back into a factor if you like.) There are various ways to shorten/streamline this (in tidyverse you would use a combination of `stringr::str_detect()` and `case_when()`). You might want to use `tolower()` as part of this to avoid problems with case differences.